# List vs Dict for list of objects with an ID

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Firstly, speed is not a massive issue here as the length of lists is relatively small. I'm more interested in style, and code-economy.

I have a graph (nodes and edges) where I need to store data for each node. I use a class like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,node_id,name,edges,[more data]):
        self.node_id = node_id
        self.name = name
        etc.
        etc.
```

My nodes are then (currently) read from a file and put into a list, like this:

```
with open("filepath.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

nodes = []

for line in content:
    lst = ast.literal_eval(line)
    nodes.append(Node([lst[0],lst[1],lst[2]...))
```

I don't really use the position of a `node` in the list `nodes` to mean anything; the node is always identified by `node_id` which is uniquely determined previously.

This means if I want to get the attribute `someData` from the node with `node_id` of 7, say, I have to use:

```
for n in nodes:
    if n.node_id == 7:
        print(n.someData)
```

which seems awfully inefficient.

So, I decided to use a dictionary, removing `node_id` from the `Node` class and using it as the key instead. A dictionary seems like the 'correct' structure to use, surely? However, in many places this has made my code worse!

For example, where before I had:

```
sumTotal = sum(n.someData for n in nodes)
```

I now have to use:

```
sumTotal = sum(nodes[k].someData for k in nodes)
```

or

```
sumTotal = sum(n.someData for n in nodes.values())
```

Am I missing something here? What would be the best practice for this type of data?

Comment: What do you consider as "worse". Just because it's a few lines longer really isn't making it "worse".  None the less, I think Dictionary has a specific use case, if you have a set of data where order matters, I would use a list. If not, than dictionary is useful since you can give each value a unique "key". This lets you look up an exact value later on very easily. The best thing I can think of is if you had a list of names and associated grades, {'John' : '100%' } for example. The user can just type in a name and get out a result without the need to first figure out an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `node_id` is a unique key, you can do this:

```
nodes = {}

for line in content:
    lst = ast.literal_eval(line)
    nodes[lst[0]] = Node(lst[0],lst[1],lst[2]...))
```

And if you need to do anything with them later it will be faster and cleaner:

```
print nodes[7].someData
```

You will have to do something like this to get the sum though:

```
sumTotal = sum(nodes[k].someData for k in nodes)
```

Comment: Yep, that function is how I'm importing into the dictionary. I agree that it is certainly neater when trying to access node data by `node_index`. It just seems that a lot of other code looks messier; when iterating through the dictionary, I have to differentiate between data in the dictionary value, and data in the dictionary key:

Comment: That is; a line in a loop like `for n in nodes:` such as `print(n.node_id + " " + n.name + " " + n.someString + " " + n.someOtherString)` becomes `print(n + " " + nodes[n].name + " " + nodes[n].someString + " " + nodes[n].someOtherString)`, which seems harder to comprehend at a quick glance.